# Disable Adobe Reader toolbar from my ActiveX

Tags: pdf, adobe, itext, toolbar, axacropdf

I am loading a PDF document in my ActiveX using AxAcroPDFLib and iTextSharp libraries. I want to disable the toolbar (that have Save, Print etc options) from the loaded PDF so that user cannot 'Save' the PDF from ActiveX.

I have following code:

```
axAcroPDF1.Width = someWidth;
axAcroPDF1.Height = someHeight;
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(documentPath);
axAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none");
axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);

axAcroPDF1.Show();
axAcroPDF1.Focus();
```

The `axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false)` disables the toolbar but the other gray toolbar enables at the bottom ( [as shown in figure on this link](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/files/2011/11/002_exit_read_mode.png)) of PDF when I move mouse in that area. That toolbar also have saving option in it and I want to disable this one as well.

It would be really nice if it allows to disable only 'Save' option and keep the other options enabled on toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking something that is impossible. Please read this [thread dating from December 2011](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/60287). You'll find a snippet where Leonard Rosenthol, Adobe's PDF architect says: "there is no way to hide the toolbar (or the HUD) in the browser."

Setting the toolbar to false works for the toolbar, but you are referring to the "Heads Up Display" (HUD). As documented by Adobe, there is no way to customize this feature, let me [quote Adobe](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/what-developers-need-to-know-about-acrobat-x):

> the "Heads Up Display" (HUD) is not customizable. There are no APIs to
>   HUD. You can’t use JavaScript to enter Read Mode, exit Read Mode or
>   detect that the document is in Read Mode. Though it might seem like
>   it, this wasn’t an oversight. There are some very sound engineering
>   reasons why this is the case but I won’t go into those here.

Comment: I have noticed that the HUD display only appears when my document is encrypted. If I remove the encryption from PDF the HUD display doesn't appears and the toolbar is also remains hidden. Now the only way user can save the document is using short keys. Is there any other way you think user can still save the PDF?

Comment: Your observation is wrong, because (1) I can reproduce the appearance of a HUD using an unencrypted PDF in Adobe Reader, (2) when opening the PDF in Firefox with pdf.js, I see a different kind of HUD, (3) Adobe Reader can only render a PDF that is stored on disk, so the bytes are out there on the end users disk anyway, (4) and so on... Your assumptions is based on your experience with a single PDF viewer. You can't control which PDF viewer will be used by the end user, so you're really trying to do something that is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 8):

I success using

```
this.axAcroPDF1.src = filePath + "#toolbar=0";
```

Comment: thanks, works fine for me. Instead of using,`Loadfile()`, same results with "src" property, and sidebar disappers :-). (reader ver.19.10.20069)

Comment: This is awesome! While this doesn't get rid of the HUD, which is what the OP is asking I think, it helped me get rid of the other toolbars, which is a great help to me. Your answer here prompted me to discover other parameters that can be passed this way as well. See: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf for details.

Answer (score 0):

I got succeed using
axAcroPDF.src = filepath + "#toolbar = 0"