# How to customize the print button in itext pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itextpdf

[image]For displaying pdf files in **java** i am using itext pdf jar.i am facing problem with customize the print button(located on top which is provided by itext).why i am customizing means,when i click on print button need to save the details of my document.for that purpose only i need to customize that button.please tell me how to use that button in my code point of view(java).please let me know.

Comment: The question is strange: "For displaying PDF files in Java, I am using iText", but... iText doesn't display PDFs, it creates PDF. You mention a "print button located on top which is provided by iText." How is this print button provided by iText? You say "When I click on print button need to save the details of my document", but what are those details? I have no idea what you mean when you say "how to use that button in my code point of view." The question should either be clarified or closed.

Comment: ok i agree with your answer,the thing is with help of itext jars i am displaying pdf file.in that pdf files on top one tool bar option is there.tool bar option contains download button and print button etc.for my purpose i need to save some details in my database.i need to customize that print according to my java code.is it possible?

Comment: How to hide toolbar option in itext pdf files?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: the toolbar / print button isn't added by iText. I see that you are using pdf.js, a PDF viewer embedded in Firefox. That toolbar is added by pdf.js, **NOT** by iText. There's a similar question (and answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081728/disable-adobe-reader-toolbar-from-my-activex/

Comment: If you want to avoid printing, you can *encrypt* the file using an owner password and make sure the permission for printing isn't set. However: whether or not this option is respected depends entirely on the viewer.